# Is there a compact way to define multiple params for a Sql Query from C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using code like this in my C# controllers. db is my EF database context.

```
var sql = @"dbo.sp_add_test  @CreatedBy,
                             @CreatedDate,
                             @TestId,
                             @TestStatusId";   

// Can the following 7 lines be combined?    
List<SqlParameter> parameterList = new List<SqlParameter>();
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@CreatedBy", Int32.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId()) ));
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@CreatedDate", DateTime.UtcNow));
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@TestId", testId));
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@TestStatusId", 3));
SqlParameter[] parameters = parameterList.ToArray();


var test = await db.Database.SqlQuery<Test>(sql, parameters).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

It seems that there may be some redundancy in that I first create a list, then do individual adds to it and then finally convert to an array.

Is there a way all of this could be combined into one statement?

Please when you answer this question can you do so in the form of an answer and not in the comments so that everyone can be helped. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using EF, why don't you map your SP in the EF context?

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo - Thank you for your suggestion. I was not aware I could do that. Can you give me an example of how this would be done. Maybe using my data but just with one parameter to keep it to a few lines.

Comment: I'd directly use an array initializer. That removes move of the boiler-plate code.

Comment: @Marilou, you import the stored procedures in the EF designer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896231.aspx

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo - I'm not trying to be rude but why give a link when you could help others by providing an example? BTW I am using EF Code First. Not sure if that makes a difference. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly initialize the array as below:

```
SqlParameter[] parameterList = new SqlParameter[]
{
    new SqlParameter("@CreatedBy", Int32.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId())),
    new SqlParameter("@CreatedDate", DateTime.UtcNow),
    new SqlParameter("@TestId", testId),
    new SqlParameter("@TestStatusId", 3)
};
```

But like the others said, if you are using EF, you can map the SP to the EF context by importing the SP to the EF context.